# When calling Firebase cloud function locally I receive a 200 response but the response is a cors type response not my actual data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, cors

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "Function url with params", 
redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "function url with params"
__proto__: Response
```

Calling the function:

```
export function authDB(token,cb){
fetch(`${apiURL}auth?token=${token}`,{
    method:"GET"
    })
    .then(cb)
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

I have set the response in my cloud function to allow cors

```
response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")   
response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST')
```

When testing with Postman, all response scenarios are actual data

Comment: Providing the complete response header would help to answer correctly. Also please mention the request method as either GET or OPTIONS request. OPTIONS request are meant for serving cors configuration in response header. make sure you are not confusing with GET and OPTIONS request

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! I needed to parse the response to Json.

```
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(cb)
```